# Chrome Animating Links On Page Load

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, animation

In Chrome only, on this site http://jacquelynchastain.com, all of the links are animating on load. There should be zero animation on this page when it loads.

[Here is the best screenshot](http://oi58.tinypic.com/30cp05h.jpg) I can get of what's happening: when the page loads, the links start off styled like the default Foundation 5 links/buttons. When loaded they assume the correct styling and the page ends up looking correct.

e.g. the default link style is a small blue font; the menu link style is a larger green font with a CSS transition. The transition is getting triggered and causing the animation from default link text to the correctly styled which is definitely undesirable. I have verified this issue is only happening in Chrome, and it seems not everyone is seeing it but some are.

Tech Specs:

I am on Mac, OSX version 10.9.4, Chrome 36.0.1985.143

This issue does not happen in Firefox, Safari, or Internet Explorer. 
I have verified with at least 7 other people on Mac and PC that it also happens in their version of Chrome.

---

**UPDATE:**

Below is the stripped back code where the problem is happening:

**Effect**: The css transition is being triggered on load somehow & the link style is being animated (i.e. grows from the default size to 2em) instead of just being applied.

**Conditions**:On Chrome only. Only happens when the css is included in the external file *AND* when there is a form element. It doesn't happen if the css is included inline, or if the form element is removed.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <p><a href="#">Test</a></p>
    <form></form>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
a{
font-size:2em;
-webkit-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
-moz-transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
transition:all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

What could be causing this?

Comment: its fine in my chrome..check your extension/toolbars

Comment: Can't see anything wrong in Chrome 36.0.1985.125. Can you post some screenshots of the problem?

Comment: It's kind of hard to since it happens so quickly, but I will try... It can't be my extension/toolbars, I checked in Chrome on another computer and had several other people test and it's also having the same issue for them. Please don't downvote. :(

Comment: [This is the closest I can get](http://oi58.tinypic.com/30cp05h.jpg). It comes in small, blue, then animates into what it should look like. It appears the button is doing it too. I'm up to date, using Chrome 36.0.1985.143.

Comment: I've added more information.. I hope this will help, I'm not entirely sure what's going on either.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it clearer & include the offending code (the question piqued my interest but I've no idea what on earth could be causing it)

Comment: Thank you so very much for your help! My lack of understanding to why it was happening made it harder for me to explain. I hope I'm able to find a solution! I've asked a few more people to check it out, and so far it seems like only 20% or less of people are seeing it while others don't see it at all.

Comment: No problem, I like to help if I can because I've got some great help on SO before, so pay it forward & all that :). To be honest, if it wasn't for the blue then you wouldn't realise it was a bug. Changing the colour in foundation css isn't ideal but it would be a quick fix until its resolved. I can only assume its a Chrome bug when it happens in bog standard html/css. I imagine people don't see the transition if the page isn't fully loaded in the 0.3sec duration.

Comment: I appreciate it. I've tested and verified now that changing the color in the foundation.css does not fix the color issue. :( Weird! And I know it's not a massive, massive deal but as a developer I want to be able to solve it. I'm in the midst of seeking a new job, and I'd hate for an employer to see that and think I made a big mistake.

Comment: Hey! I think I figured it out! It looks like I removed a file Foundation requires you to use, modernizer.js. I've always been kinda skeptical about what this really contributed to the page because it made it load a little slower and Google developer tools reads it back as a "render blocking script", but it looks like it's necessary for the page to function properly. I'll add this as an answer and close the question, thank you!

Comment: Like you, I shy away from anything except necessary includes & I've never needed modernizr in a project yet. I thought it was really only for compatibility with older browsers. I've always applied css transitions to the containing block instead of an `a` directly, so never came across this problem. I was going to suggest moving the css transition to the containing `div`, but that won't transition the `a` style so forget that :) Glad you got sorted anyway! I'm the same, I always want to solve problems properly (even this, which wasn't my issue!). Good luck with the job hunt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the file 'modernizer.js' is absolutely necessary for this page to function properly.

I had removed it in lieu of receiving an email with a few tips on how I could improve my page, and a reminder that I was not linking to the file properly and it was 404'ing. Now-- why the page was working before when I didn't even link to this file properly but had it on the page, I'm not sure. Adding the file back to the page and correctly linking to it has resolved my issue, though! Thank you to everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I could see the blue you mean on loading the page.

From using the element inspector I can see the default link colour is blue and your links in .mainnav are green in a larger font. Your mainnav links also have a css transition, and what you are seeing is the transformation from the initial small blue text to the larger green text on pageload.

The best way to troubleshoot something like this is to strip back everything and see what happens as you add it back piece by piece. e.g. Are you adding classes via Javascript that cause the transition to trigger?

For a quick fix, try changing the default link colour in foundation.css to green so there is no colour transition.

FYI you have normalize.min.css and foundation.min.css commented out in your code, so no its nothing to do with how you are importing them :)

Comment: Up until I updated parts of the site today, I wasn't having any problems with the links. I'm not adding any classes via Javascript on the links. I can try making the foundation.css links green, but typically that file isn't one you want to mess with. And yes, they are being imported, I have them commented out of the HTML but they are being imported within a LESS file. I was wondering if my importing into the LESS file was causing problems versus directly linking to the external stylesheets in the HTML.. but that wasn't it. :( Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I will also say I am not seeing this issue happen on my local files. It only happens on the live site.

Comment: As I suggested the best way to troubleshoot is to start with the basics and add the relevant parts back bit by bit to identify the offending code. You may even be that you didn't see it before of pageload speed. There isn't much else we can do without details so come back and update your question when you identify the cause if you're still having problems.

Comment: I could easily recreate it locally with just your plain html from View Source & style.css (no normalise.min.css, foundation.min.css, js etc). Try starting your troubleshooting from there.

Comment: It's just super weird... It wasn't doing this until something I changed today. [Here's another site I built in a similar manner](http://colingimenez.com/) and it's not having the issue. Would you be able to tell any differences between the two that might be causing this?